# squid request/response analysis

Tags: squid

How can I get a report on Squid request/response, something similar to Apache server-status ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use squidclient:

```
squidclient -h localhost -p 3128 mgr:info
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: squid/3.1.6
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2011 06:51:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Expires: Wed, 02 Mar 2011 06:51:49 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 02 Mar 2011 06:51:49 GMT
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128
Via: 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.6)
Proxy-Connection: close

Squid Object Cache: Version 3.1.6
Start Time: Wed, 02 Mar 2011 06:50:08 GMT
Current Time:   Wed, 02 Mar 2011 06:51:49 GMT
Connection information for squid:
    Number of clients accessing cache:  1
    Number of HTTP requests received:   1
    Number of ICP messages received:    0
    Number of ICP messages sent:    0
    Number of queued ICP replies:   0
    Number of HTCP messages received:   0
    Number of HTCP messages sent:   0
    Request failure ratio:   0.00
    Average HTTP requests per minute since start:   0.6
    Average ICP messages per minute since start:    0.0
    Select loop called: 29980 times, 3.352 ms avg
...
```

Also try mgr:refresh, mgr:counters, mgr:utilization, mgr:mem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There many options but not exactly like Apache server-status.

[squidview](http://www.rillion.net/squidview/)

[squint](http://www.ledge.co.za/software/squint/index.php)

[Squid Logfile Analysis](http://www.squid-cache.org/Scripts/)